# People Posting Pointless Pictures

Tags: discussion, images

I get annoyed with people putting unnecessary images in their questions and answers, but I wonder if there is any rational objection to the practice, or is it just irrational prejudice on my part? Is there anything ***wrong*** with posting a useless image, aside from making me waste my precious time scrolling past the picture so I can read the post?

Comment: -1 question has no pictures

Comment: @randal'thor Perhaps a time to mention we could link to [how to thumbnail uploaded images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/287266) in some FAQ post.

Comment: @CreationEdge Good idea. Maybe post it as a suggestion on the FAQ proposals thread?

Comment: Is there a particular post that has irked you?

Comment: I'd say posting a tangential image shouldn't be any different from putting in tangential text. If you put in tangential text, you'll waste a bit of the reader's time - and, if you put too much of it in without something excellent to offset it, the post may be closed for length/quality reasons. Or it will be edited out. And, unless you're funny, you'll get downvotes. But there is no hard rule forbidding any text that isn't necessary. I think there's no reason why images should be treated differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I've expanded this answer quite a bit from its original version.  Even though the Question is a duplicate, I thought a more complete answer covering the current status of including images would be useful.)

I don't think much has changed since [an earlier version of this question was asked 4 years ago:](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1840/what-is-up-with-all-the-tangential-imagery)

- images that illustrate exactly what's being said in the text are useful, even if there are a lot of them (e.g. ["Batman wore such-and-such armour in this situation."](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/why-doesnt-batman-make-an-armored-suit-like-ironman))
- images that are large and require a lot of scrolling to go past are distracting
- unrelated or barely-related images in posts are distracting and many people (myself among them) find them annoying
- there's a wide range of opinion as to what's related or not

## How bad is the problem?

Not bad at all, IMO.

I spent some time looking at questions with images in them (search for imgur urls) and I didn't find too many that I thought were pointless:

- looking just at questions, there are about 50 per month that have imgur links
- even though I'm "prejudiced" against images, I'd say at least 50% of them are clearly relevant, and another 20%-30% are *probably* useful - I didn't think they were totally relevant, but I had to agree they were at least useful to illustrate something in the question
- most of the images I thought weren't relevant were from relatively new users who probably just haven't developed a good sense yet of what's relevant or not

So overall I think *at most 10% of images that get posted aren't relevant* and could be edited out.

### What to do about it

There are a few options:

- Don't do anything, it's not actually that big a problem.
- Edit posts and remove links to irrelevant images.  If editing old questions, limit edits to one or two at a time so they don't overwhelm the front page.
- If the images are hosted on stack.imgur, it's easy to edit a question to convert large images to thumbnails:

If the image URL is: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGbrX.png`

You can add an `m` or a `t` to the end of the filename to make the image a thumbnail.

This: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGbrXm.png` makes the largest dimension 320 pixels.

And this: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGbrXt.png` makes it a thumbnail with 160 pixels max.

I think this is the how you do an "m" thumbnail with a link to the original picture:

```
[![picture whose claim I am skeptical of][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa5kLm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa5kL.png
```

[More details on thumbnails on meta.StackExchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow/108821#108821)

Again, if editing old questions, only do a couple at a time.

### Fair use

This has gotten to be a bit long, so I'll just mention that one of the [answers to the earlier question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1848/4167) has some good comments on fair use.